# ¿Se pueden actualizar registros en sqlite en todos los dispositivos que tengan instalada la app?

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite, app

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Android Studio usando una base de datos sqlite y quiero saber si después de instalada la app en varios dispositivos, ¿Se pueden actualizar los datos de esa base de datos de tal modo que todos los usuarios que tengan instalada la app puedan percibir esos cambios?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

De manera automatica no, pero puedes enviar un request a tu servidor cada vez que un registro de tu base de datos en la aplicacion sea actualizada para que este (Tu Servidor) emita una notificación PUSH hacia todos los usuarios con una app (Similar a las notificaciones de las aplicaciones) la cual llame a un método sincronizar bd al abrir la app.

La otra opcion es que la app cada cierto tiempo consulte al servidor si hay cambios nuevos con un versionado de información.

Comment: Pero al implementar Sqlite no estoy usando ningún tipo de servidor, ¿Crees que debería usarlo? ó...¿Sería mejor usar otro tipo de base de datos?

Comment: Sqlite es una base de datos basado en un archivo físico alojado en el dispositivo movil, es como tener un txt con información, la única forma de mantener las bases de datos de todos los usuarios sincronizados es controlar los cambios desde un servidor.

Comment: Comprendo, muchas gracias amigo!